# PHP specific merge array

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays

```
$arr1 = array(1,3);  
$arr2 = array(2,4);
```

I want merge them to one array with structure:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4);
```

Has php functions for that or exist good solution?
UPD: i don't need sort values, i want put elements from first array to odd positions, elements from second to even positions

Comment: you should clarify -- do you want this: new_array = array( arr1[0], arr2[0], arr1[1], arr2[1] ); regardless of the values in the arrays? Meaning you can't just apply a sort but rather you want to merge two arrays so that the same index from arr1 and arr2 are always next to one another?

Comment: How about the lengths of the arrays? (Write your own function then. That's not so difficult.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would have to [`merge`](http://www.php.net/array_merge) them first, then [`sort`](http://www.php.net/sort) them:

```
$arr = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
sort($arr);
```

There is no built-in function to do what you are describing, assuming they are both the same length:

```
$len = count($arr1);
for($x=0; $x < $len; $x++) {
    array_push($arr, $arr1[$x], $arr2[$x]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_arr = array_merge($arr1, $arr2)
```

Comment: key your arrays with odd keys and/or even keys, then use asort and you can accomplish what you're talking about in your update

Answer (score 0):

No. Php does not have a function for this that I know of. You'll have to write your own, but it's very simple.

Pseudocode:

```
cmb = []

for (i=0, i<arr1.length, i++) {
   array_push(cmb, arr1[i]);
   array_push(cmb, arr2[i]);
}
```